# How to check if all items in a group are contained in a string for many items? - RegEx

Tags: sql, regex, list, presto, regexp-like

I'm planning on embedding RegEx in my SQL query so can't really use a loop for this.

Essentially, I'm trying to check a series of groups to see if the name of my column contains all the attributes of any of those individual groups (i.e. groups must be checked against independently and not altogether).

For example,

```
group1 = l, w, q
group2 = o, l, d
```

If the column name contains all the items in `group1` (e.g. `low_quality`) should return `true`. Similarly, `cold` would also return `true` since it matches against every item in `group2`.

How would I go about validating whether or not my column name contains every item in any group? (items can be >1 character and I have around 40 groups to test against).

Could something along the following lines be modified?

```
SELECT column_name,
       (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column_name, ((?=l)(?=w)(?=q))|((?=o)(?=l)(?=d))) THEN true ELSE NULL
        END) AS flag
FROM information_schema.columns;
```

I'm just not sure how to check against multiple groups independently.

Comment: I think you  can try `REGEXP_LIKE(column_name, '^(?:(?=.*l)(?=.*w)(?=.*q)|(?=.*o)(?=.*l)(?=.*d))')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
REGEXP_LIKE(column_name, '^(?:(?=.*l)(?=.*w)(?=.*q)|(?=.*o)(?=.*l)(?=.*d))')
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group matching either of the two patterns:

  - `(?=.*l)(?=.*w)(?=.*q)` - `l`, `w` or `q` in any order
- `|` - or

  - `(?=.*o)(?=.*l)(?=.*d)` - `o`, `l` or `d` in any order
- `)`  - end of the group.